# What should be the Http status code for "you're not allowed to do that...yet"?

Tags: rest, http, http-status-codes

Please tell me what should the status codes be for the case below:

A user has registered but hasn't provided her personal info that we need to let her buy from us. Yet she attempts to purchase anyway.

***My thought :*** forbidden - 403. but 403 says the request shouldn't be repeated. that's wrong I want her to repeat the exact request only after she visits her personal info route and provides the info and then comes back.

Comment: [409 Conflict](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.8) might be a valid error code (depending on the current state of the resource)

Comment: @RomanVottner yeah. I like that.. How come this status never crossed my  eye...

Answer (score 0):

I would argue this falls under the 412 Precondition failed status code. The client hasn't provided the necessary information in order to make a successful request, because a condition is missing.

From [RFC 7232](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#page-19):

> The 412 (Precondition Failed) status code indicates that one or more
> conditions given in the request header fields evaluated to false when
> tested on the server.  This response code allows the client to place
> preconditions on the current resource state (its current
> representations and metadata) and, thus, prevent the request method
> from being applied if the target resource is in an unexpected state.

Comment: The problem here is, that the actual request should already contain a header like `If-Unmodified-Since` or similar which may or may not fail. In case it fails, a precondition failure should be returned.

Comment: It is unclear from OPs question whether this is the case or not.